# Parse jar filenames

Tags: regex, bash, jar, filenames

Let's say you want the *best* pattern to extract both name and version from a jar filename. I got something *not so bad* which works on [regexr](http://regexr.com) but not with bash. This is because bash does not support non-greedy regex. So how should one handle this?

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="./log4j-enhanced-3.5.100-v20130422-1538.jar"

if [[ "$filename" =~ \.\/(.*?)-([0-9].*)\.jar ]]; then
        echo "name    =  ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "version =  ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi

# expected :
# name    = log4j-enhanced
# version = 3.5.100-v20130422-1538
```

Usage of unix utilities is ok, but please make it readable.

Comment: `\.\/([[:alnum:]-]*)-([0-9].*)\.jar`

Comment: If the bash operator `=~` **did** support non-greedy, wouldn't you expect `name = log4j`, not `name = log4j-enhanced`?

Comment: @drewyupdrew no I would expect `log4j-enhanced`, because it is everything before the first dash followed by a digit is encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU bash's [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32) :

```
filename="./log4j-enhanced-3.5.100-v20130422-1538.jar"

filename="${filename#./}"
name="${filename%%-[0-9]*}" 
version="${filename#$name-}"
version="${version%.jar}"

echo "name    = $name"
echo "version = $version"
```

Output:

```
name    = log4j-enhanced
version = 3.5.100-v20130422-1538
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
filename="./log4j-enhanced-3.5.100-v20130422-1538.jar"

if [[ "$filename" =~ [.]/([[:alnum:]-]*)-([0-9].*)[.]jar ]]; then
        echo "name    =  ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "version =  ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
fi
```

See the [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/QNqOmd)

The `[[:alnum:]-]*` will greedily match alphanumeric and hyphen characters up to a hyphen followed with a digit.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is nice, but I think the accepted answer covers [more situations](http://ideone.com/JZtmK8).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish the same thing without using Bash's special features, here is what you can do:

```
#!/bin/sh
filename="./log4j-enhanced-3.5.100-v20130422-1538.jar"

regex='.\/\(.*\)-\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+.*\)\.jar'

name="$(echo $filename | sed -e "s/$regex/\1/")"
version="$(echo $filename | sed -e "s/$regex/\2/")"

echo "   name: $name"
echo "version: $version"
```

Output:

```
   name: log4j-enhanced
version: 3.5.100-v20130422-1538
```